# How "add" two GETs in a link in PHP

Tags: php, get

There are two menus and both were made in order to filter the main content of my website. The Menu one will filter the category and the Menu two will filter the brand.

When clicking in a menu 01 option, it will output: `mywebsite.com/?cat=accessories`

When clicking in a menu 02 option, it will output: `mywebsite.com/?brand=medicate`

My main question is how can I get both together when one of them is already set, something like: `mywebsite.com/?category=accessories&brand=medicate`

Here is my basic code:

```
<h1>Menu One</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?category=accessories">Option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?category=bolts">Option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?category=tools">Option 01</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Menu Two</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="&brand=medicate">Brand 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="&brand=diasyst">Brand 02</a></li>
  <li><a href="&brand=clement">Brand 03</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your example is the correct way to do it. Did you try it? (PHP terminology calls those: query string parameters)

Comment: Yes u can use it `category=accessories&brand=medicate` and get by print_r($_GET);

Comment: I would recommend using a form with 2 select boxes. Otherwise you'll have to hard code links for each combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're displaying the menus, if one of the other filters is already set, you can add that to the URL in the other menu.

```
$cat = isset($_GET['category']) ? '&category=' . $_GET['category'] : '';
$brand = isset($_GET['brand']) ? '&brand=' . $_GET['brand'] : '';
?>

<h1>Menu One</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?category=accessories<?php echo $brand ?>">Option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?category=bolts<?php echo $brand ?>">Option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?category=tools<?php echo $brand ?>">Option 01</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Menu Two</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?brand=medicate<?php echo $cat ?>">Brand 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=diasyst<?php echo $cat ?>">Brand 02</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=clement<?php echo $cat ?>">Brand 03</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding right your question but it seems to me you want to do?

```
<h1>Menu Join</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?brand=medicate&category=accessories">Brand 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=diasyst&category=accessories">Brand 02</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=clement&category=accessories">Brand 03</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, that would be the obviously way to do, however, I am trying to get together both of them when one is at least set. For instance: when clicking on menu option 01 it will output `mywebsite.com/?category=accessories`. If is category set, when clicking on menu option two it will output something like `mywebsite.com/?category=accessories&brand=medicate`

Answer (score 0):

i guess that's what you are asking for:

```
<h1>Menu One</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?brand=<?php echo $_GET["brand"]; ?>&category=accessories">Option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=<?php echo $_GET["brand"]; ?>&category=bolts">Option 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=<?php echo $_GET["brand"]; ?>&category=tools">Option 01</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Menu Two</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?brand=medicate&category=<?php echo $_GET["category"]; ?>">Brand 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=diasyst&category=<?php echo $_GET["category"]; ?>">Brand 02</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=clement&category=<?php echo $_GET["category"]; ?>">Brand 03</a></li>
</ul>
```

this will work for your exact case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the known parameter to the links as well.

```
<?php
  $category = isset($_GET['category']) ? '&category='.$_GET['category'] : '');
  $brand = isset($_GET['brand']) ? '&brand='.$_GET['brand'] : '');
?>
<h1>Menu One</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?category=accessories<?php echo $brand; ?>">Accessories</a></li>
  <li><a href="?category=bolts<?php echo $brand; ?>">Bolts</a></li>
  <li><a href="?category=tools<?php echo $brand; ?>">Tools</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Menu Two</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="?brand=medicate<?php echo $category; ?>">Medicate</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=diasyst<?php echo $category; ?>">Diasyst</a></li>
  <li><a href="?brand=clement<?php echo $category; ?>">Clement</a></li>
</ul>
```

Considering you are using PHP, you can compile the menu a lot more dynamically than hardcoding all options. But an explanation of that is beyond this question. Consider that just a general tip.